# Java streams compare object from two streams and create new Object

Tags: java, java-stream

I have two Lists:

```java
List<Object1> listOne = provider.getObjects().stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
List<Object2> listTwo = provider2.getObjects().stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Now I want create List containg all possible `Object1`-`Object2` combinations: `List<ObjectCombinations> result;`

```java
class ObjectCombinations { 
    Object1 object1; 
    Object2 object2;

    public ObjectCombinations(Object1 object1, Object2 object2)  { 
        this.object1 = object1;
        this.object2 = object2;
    }
}
```

How is that possible with java 8 streams?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `flatMap` to get all the combinations:

```
List<ObjectCombinations> result =
    listOne.stream()
           .flatMap(o1 -> listTwo.stream()
                                 .map(o2 -> new ObjectCombinations(o1,o2)))
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

First you create a `Stream<Object1>`, then you use `flatMap` to combine each element of that stream with all the elements of `listTwo`, and create the `ObjectCombinations` instances, which you collect to a `List`.

Comment: What if we use map instead of flatmap?

Comment: @JeetKumar you will get a different result (a `Stream<Stream<ObjectCombinations>>` instead of `Stream<ObjectCombinations>`, which will be collected to a `List<Stream<ObjectCombinations>>` instead of `List<ObjectCombinations>`).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `flatMap` where you can stream over 2nd list and create ObjectCombinations and flatten the list.

```
List<ObjectCombinations> res = 
       listOne.stream()
              .flatMap(a -> listTwo.stream().map(b -> new ObjectCombinations(a,b)))
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```